# Swipe contents while background remains same

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create mobile website using jQuery mobile. My requirement is that, only contents of each page is need to be changed while swiping , background image remains the same. And i also need pagination to each pages. Is possible to make background stick to the content?

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/PtEnY/5/

Set background image to html, body and remove background of `.ui-page`

Use this css,

```
html, body{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-YUUHSmN2iKc/URqH5KMr6OI/AAAAAAAABpE/ta3lwt2KDx8/s1600/desktop-wallpaper-1600x1200.jpg) no-repeat fixed left top !important;    
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    -moz-background-size: cover !important;
    -o-background-size: cover !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
.ui-page, .ui-page-active{
    background:none !important;
}
```

Comment: On scroll down background is also scrolling in some browsers. Do you why? can you help to resolve.

Comment: in which browsers? pls let me know.